# R Studio on Mac - latex command not working

Tags: r, latex, survival-analysis, hmisc

I am trying to use latex function to output regression formula.
like this:

```
require(rms)`
f <- cph(Surv(...) ~ ...)`
latex(f)`
```

but getting an error I don't understand.
I installed Xcode, MacTeX.
Can anyone help me?

Maybe it is a data error?

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
> restricted \write18 enabled.
> entering extended mode
>
> (/var/folders/y8/dcqwxmkn4qgd15mj86hyt1sr0000gp/T//RtmpN1ROBO/file1416d26bf8cef
> .tex
> LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
> L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
> Document Class: report 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
> No file file1416d26bf8cef.aux.
> *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
> *geometry* detected driver: dvips
>
> Overfull \hbox (1097.7373pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--12
>
> [1] (./file1416d26bf8cef.aux) )
> (see the transcript file for additional information)
> Output written on file1416d26bf8cef.dvi (1 page, 1144 bytes).
> Transcript written on file1416d26bf8cef.log.
> Error: Can't open display: :0
> There were 17 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

and those 17 warnings:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 2: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 3: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 4: In is.na(xj) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 5: In is.na(xk) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 6: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 7: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 8: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 9: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 10: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 11: In is.na(xj) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 12: In is.na(xk) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 13: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 14: In is.na(xj) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 15: In is.na(xk) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
> 16: In cbind(cx, cxk) :
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
> 17: In system(cmd, intern = TRUE, wait = TRUE) :
> running command 'xdvi -paper 5.5x7in -s 0 /var/folders/y8/dcqwxmkn4qgd15mj86hyt1sr0000gp/T//RtmpN1ROBO/file1416d26bf8cef.dvi' had status 1

Comment: Cannot be reproduced without the data and needed prep work for running `rms` code.

Comment: Also sounds like the problem was that the "page" was not wide enough. Why not increase the size of the device?